# Rotate a polygon drawn with GraphicsPath

Tags: vb.net, graphics, polygon, rotatetransform

I'd like to rotate a polygon by -90 degrees at the upper right corner.

Here's my code to draw the polygon :

```
Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()
    Dim p As New Drawing2D.GraphicsPath()

    Dim startPoint As Point = PointToClient(Cursor.Position)

    Dim littleAngle As Integer = 4
    Dim anglesDifference As Integer = 2
    Dim bigAngle As Integer = littleAngle + anglesDifference
    Dim bigSegment As Integer = 50

    Dim p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 As Point

    p1 = New Point(startPoint.X + littleAngle, startPoint.Y - littleAngle)
    p2 = New Point(startPoint.X + littleAngle + bigSegment, startPoint.Y - littleAngle)
    p3 = New Point(startPoint.X + littleAngle + bigSegment + littleAngle, startPoint.Y)
    p4 = New Point(startPoint.X + littleAngle - anglesDifference + bigSegment, startPoint.Y + bigAngle)
    p5 = New Point(startPoint.X + bigAngle, startPoint.Y + bigAngle)

    p.AddLines({startPoint, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5})

    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
    g.FillPath(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), p)
    g.DrawPath(pen, p)

    Dim translateMatrix As New Matrix
    translateMatrix.RotateAt(-90, New PointF(p.GetBounds.Width, 0))
    p.Transform(translateMatrix)

    g.FillPath(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), p)
    g.DrawPath(pen, p)
End Sub
```

Here's what is drawn using the code above :

[image: the result I've]

And here's an example of what I'd like to have :

[image]

Comment: You really should be using the `Paint` event for painting and use the `e.Graphics`.

Comment: @OneFineDay Why? His code is fine; there was just a small geometrical issue. His current approach is called only when required (i.e., on form click; which might be moved to a button click or to any other event). On the other hand, the paint-based modification you are suggesting would be called lots of times and might not be easily adapted to other situations.

Comment: @varocarbas You're right, it's why I didn't use his advice.

Comment: So you don't want your drawing to persist? What happens when you minimize the form and bring it back? Where is your drawing now?

Comment: @OneFineDay For the moment it was just a test for another of my projects. So I wasn't in care of this because I just wanted to draw correctly my polygon... But thank you ;) By the way it's why I'm using the cursor position to relatively draw the polygon and not a button or something else : I just wanted to test ^^

Comment: Great, but you two are acting like it was bad advise - and it is not. Plus if you create the Graphics object - you should dispose it. You don't have to dispose the e.Graphics object as it is done for you.

Comment: Another consequence is that the Graphics instance obtained from the `CreateGraphics` call is not necessarily the same one used by the Windows  Paint event.  For example, if the form is double buffered, the `Graphics` instance provided in the Paint event is to an in memory bitmap whereas the one from CreateGraphics is not.

Comment: @OneFineDay In this context, it is a bad advice. The original code (when working properly) is OK for what is meant. The paint event is too aggressive (being called lots of times) and should be avoided when possible. This seems one of these situations.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway You don't know the exact purpose of this code. As said above, the current version is 100% portable and can be used in any situation. Depending upon the specific conditions, it might be worthy to consider the paint event (of this control or of any other one); but always by bearing in mind that these events are called many times and should be avoided when possible. Thus, a priori and before knowing the exact usage of this code, the original non-paint-dependent version seems better to me.

Comment: @varocarbas, you can control/take over the painting and stop the system from painting. That is not a good argument. When I was learning GDI+ everyone said the same things I have said. Now all of the sudden it is bad - sorry don't believe you I have done too much research.

Comment: @OneFineDay Don't believe me?! OK. Up to you. In any case, I am not saying that it is bad; I am saying that it shouldn't be recommended by default (for example, in this case). By default, better relying on something on which you have full control, not on something which is called automatically an unpredictable number of times.

Comment: Don't fight for me ! x)

Comment: LOL. I am not fighting for you. I am fighting for the future readers. Additionally there is no fight. This is a polite discussion to clarify an issue. When you propose/criticise something, you should be ready to defend your position with reasons and/or learn. Arguments on the lines of "I have been told that"/"I thought that"... are not too valid; much less when trying to share knowledge with others, like here.

Comment: Yeah, I don't feel like I'm fighting either. Everything I have read states `CreateGraphics` is almost always the wrong choice. It was meant for a very limited use. Even the OP said it was just for testing - that is fine, but what happens when the graphics needs to persist? It won't in his application and that is what I was pointing out. Plus all graphics objects should be disposed if you create them - which they did not and also pointed out as best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, just replace `translateMatrix.RotateAt(-90, New PointF(p.GetBounds.Width, 0))` with:

```
translateMatrix.RotateAt(-90, p3)
```